# ios UITabBar is huge. Takes up 50% of scene

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbar

The following scenes looked normal the last time I closed XCode. Today the TabBar takes up 50% of the scene.

Adding custom images fixes the issue if I add them to the individual scenes that make up the storyboard (tab then nav then scene)

Has anyone seen similar and managed to fix it?

[image: Without custom image added]

[image: Custom Images added to Nav (middle scene) and visible scene (right)]

Comment: please add the entire context of what you actually do with that poor tab-bar to distort so badly.

Comment: absolutely out-of-the-box. Dragged from the Object library onto the storyboard.